# Django redirect not works

Tags: django

I would like to redirect to another view if a condition is met, but the redirect functionality not show the template, blank screen.

I have tried with this.

views.py

```
class CustomSendView(LoginRequiredMixin, View, PermissionRequiredMixin):
  model = None

  def get(self, request, id=None, *args, **kwargs):

    if int(self.element.status) != 4:
      print(reverse('app:' + self.model.__name__.lower() + '_detail', kwargs={"id": str(self.element.id)})) #/app/presupuestos/27/ver/
      return redirect(reverse('app:' + self.model.__name__.lower() + '_detail', kwargs={"id": str(self.element.id)}))

    return render(request, ...
```

urls.py

```
# Detail
path('presupuestos/<str:id>/ver/',
  app_views.CustomDetailView.as_view(
    model=app_models.Budget),
  name='budget_detail'),
```

The redirect works, this is the django server output:

```
[17/Feb/2020 18:35:14] "GET /app/presupuestos/27/send HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Feb/2020 18:35:15] "GET /app/presupuestos/27/ver/ HTTP/1.1" 200 41908
```

UPDATED
the render template in get method of CustomS endView it's shown on a modal, could affect to the redirect ?

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you call `/app/presupuestos/27/ver/` directly (by pasting it into the browser)?

Comment: with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/presupuestos/27/ver/` works well

Comment: Could you add the code of CustomDetailView and maybe even its template - the most important parts of it. The redirect obviously works, so the problem seems to be with the CustomDetailView or its template.

Comment: Can you add `CustomDetailView` to your question?